# initWithContentsOfURL returns nil on iOS 7 on device; fine in Simulator

Tags: nsmutablearray, plist, ios7

This ran fine before upgrading to iOS 7 and XCode 5:

```
NSMutableArray *test;test=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://avia.se/iphone/gillabilen/test.xml"]];
```

As you can see, the URL loads fine in a browser. It validates as UTF-8. The method isn't deprecated.

It returns nil running tethered to an Iphone 4 running iOS 7. Works fine in Simulator 7.0.

I'm completely stumped here! :) Any advice appreciated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about another problem than in topic, it turns out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
 NSArray *a = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://avia.se/iphone/gillabilen/test.xml"]];
 NSLog(@"%@", a);
```

Returning in my console :

[image]

Comment: (null) in console. I'm switching to Windows and re-saving in Notepad++.

Comment: Ah, you're running in Simulator? Just tried that now, works fine. My Simulator is version 7.0, does that guaranteedly mean it's running iOS 7? Edited my question with the updated info.

Comment: It's run and work correctly for me for :
iPad iOS 6.1, iPhone 4 iOS 7.0, simulator iOS 6 and 7.

Comment: Then it's time to "just try some things", I think. Maybe even the infamous "Have you restarted your computer?". :)

Comment: Nop, but you, you can try to clean your project, kill the application and restart XCode ;)

Comment: Are there Reachability issues in iOS 7? The Wifi was down so we had to restart the router. So now it obviously works, however there was no alert from Reachability so I didn't notice.

Comment: ... ^^ so, implement reachability in your project :) it's work fine now ? with my code for you ?

Comment: Yes, my original code also worked, of course. I have Reachability implemented so that I shouldn't get a crash if the user has no internet access. It didn't fire for some reason. Anyway, this can be closed as the problem in topic wasn't the problem. Thanks for helping me in the right direction anyway :)

Comment: Nice, next time I will think about internet connection :)